# How can you validate a single primary record from a collection of has many records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

In a Rails application I have a `team` model, and a team has many `members`. The member model has a `is_primary_contact` boolean field. A team can have 0 or 1 primary contact team members. I'm a bit stuck on how to go about writing a validation rule in order to enforce this restriction. Should be on the `team` or the `member`?

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is with a simple validation on the `member` model that validates the uniqueness of that field. What you then do is only validate this in the event that it is true, so something like

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :is_primary_contact, if: is_primary_contact?
end
```

I haven't tested this code so give it a go, but it should cover what you're after :)

Comment: This looks pretty close, but I think you would want to scope this to the team: `validates :is_primary_contact, uniqueness: { scope: team_id }, if: :is_primary_contact?`. Without the scope, only one member across all teams could have `is_primary_contact == 1`. Also, as an aside, the newer/shorter validation macros are generally preferred (http://thelucid.com/2010/01/08/sexy-validation-in-edge-rails-rails-3/).